# How do I store a signature block, including formatting, in a Sql server table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I've been assigned the task of creating a table that stores an email signature for each username. The question is, how should I store the signature block? I could use a regular varchar type, but then how do I store the formatting metadata?

Any ideas or suggestions would be welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: Before you decide how to store, decide on what limit you want to set about the number of characters, because this could grow very quickly.
Also, be very specific with your end users about what kind of signatures you will allow, e.g. HTML, RTF, plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use varchar(max), or whatever length limit is appropriate.

otherwise, the only real concern is that you might want to make sure the html is html-encoded before you stick it in the database.  (i.e., replace `<` with `&lt;`, etc.)  Not sure what you're using, but some tools have a setting so you don't have to do it manually.

other things you can do besides / in addition to html-encoding

1) restrict the formatting tags to some pre-defined set (i.e., search/replace tags you don't want before doing the insert.  You can manage this in your db stored procedure, or better yet, in your front-end (if you have control over that).

2) disqualify attempts to insert data if they include certain tags (like '`<script>`', etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Another idea I had was that you could design a specific email signature template, and then let people specify fields, such as Username, quote, avatar, alignment etc, and then have them modify their signature in a "signature editor". This way you could just store the "data" and not the rendering. so you could store something like follows:

```
<signature>
    <username>chama</username>
    <avatar href="http://url to my image"/>
    <quote>A bird in the hand is not in the nest</quote>
</signature>
```

and it could look something like:

---

[image]   **Chama**

*A bird in the hand is not in the nest*

---

Answer (score 0):

HTML, RTF, XML. The stanard choices are multiple.

Note: "email signature" is NOT "digital signature". The term digital signature has a specific meaning and means a SIGNATURE to make sure - for email - it comes from th real sender and has not been tampered with.

Comment: Thanks. Tags have been edited. I didn't think I was talking about a digital signature, but I wasn't sure what else to call it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest going with your initial thought -- `varchar(max)`. This will allow you to store signatures that are ASCII based. This includes plaintext, RTF or HTML signatures.

If users want to embed images (i.e. not a link to an image), then you'd have to determine a way for the caller to convert those images to Base64 or other before storing and after reading from your table.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I'm finding, you have basically two options:

1) Convert your formatted signature data to Binary and store it as a BLOB. 
2) Instead of saving the signature itself in the DB, save them as files somewhere and store a reference to that file location in the DB.